# How to rotate a span around the center of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas with an image:

[image]

On the right side of the picture you can see a white square with a refresh icon a little bit hidden by the black circle. I created this like that:

```
var rotatorSpan = document.createElement("span");
rotatorSpan.id = _this.idRotator;
rotatorSpan.className = "glyphicons glyphicons-restart";

document.getElementById("canvas-overlay").appendChild(rotatorSpan);
```

In my draw function:

```
this.drawRotator = function() {
    var pivotX = _this.x + (_this.imageWidth / 2);
    var pivotY = _this.y + (_this.imageHeight / 2);
    var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((_this.x - pivotX), 2) + Math.pow((_this.y - pivotY), 2));
    var rotatorX = _this.x + (_this.imageWidth / 2) + radius;
    var rotatorY = _this.y + (_this.imageHeight / 2) + (_this.indicatorRadius / 2);

    _this.ctx.save();
    _this.ctx.translate(pivotX, pivotY);
    _this.ctx.rotate(_this.rotation);
    _this.ctx.translate(-pivotX, -pivotY);
    _this.ctx.beginPath();
    _this.ctx.arc(rotatorX, rotatorY, this.indicatorRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    _this.ctx.closePath();
    _this.ctx.fill();
    _this.ctx.restore();

    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.top = rotatorY + "px";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.left = rotatorX + "px";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.fontSize = "1em";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.border = "1px solid #000;";
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.zIndex = 1000;
    document.getElementById(_this.idRotator).style.transform = "rotate(" + _this.rotation + "rad)";
};
```

Now when i rotate my picture:

[image]

you can see that everything is rotating except the white square with the refresh icon. It just rotates around its own center point.

**The Question**

How can i rotate that white square (the span element i created) around the center point of my image?

Comment: The math is not the problem it can be calculated easily. I just have no idea how to do the css transformation to rotate the span around the center point since `style.transform = "rotate(3.2rad)"` only rotates around the center point fo the span.

Comment: try setting the `transformOrigin` css property to the center of the image relatively, so if the image is at 200px, 200px from the image, `transformOrigin` will be `-(200 - (imgWidth / 2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `transform-origin` to set center of rotation. Here is a working demo. Note that this property may not work in older versions of web browsers [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.square{
    background:black;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
   -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100px 100px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```